# Is this a sufficient proof that if $M$ and $N$ are midpoints of $AD$ and $BC$ respectively, then $\vec{MN} = \frac{1}{2}(\vec{AB} + \vec{DC})$?

Tags: proof-verification, vectors

[image: Is this a sufficient proof that if $M$ and $N$ are midpoints of $AD$ and $BC$ respectively, then $\vec{MN} = \frac{1}{2}(\vec{AB} + \vec{DC})$?]

Proof: It can be proved that $\vec{MN} = \frac{1}{2}(\vec{MC} + \vec{MB})$, so it would suffice to show that $\vec{AB} + \vec{DC} = \vec{MC} + \vec{MB}$. $\vec{AB} + \vec{DC} = \vec{MC} + \vec{MB} \iff \vec{AB} - \vec{MB} = \vec{MC} - \vec{DC} \iff \vec{AB} + \vec{BM} = \vec{MC}+ \vec{CD} \iff \vec{AM} = \vec{MD} \text{ which is obviously true.}$

Comment: looks correct ${}$